# Polymer custom element styling not working in Firefox (data binding issue?)

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, polymer

The following element works fine in Chrome, but not in firefox.
What I'm expecting to see is my theme colours, which is defined in a separate place.

Now in firefox, the component itself renders, and it even creates the `.swatch` div, with the correct size of 40x40, as specified in the shadow dom styles. Unfortunately the `background-color` and `border` css rules are never applied.

The console output in firefox and chrome is exactly as I would expect, with the correct colours, which tells me that the values does exist, but for some reason the data is not bound to the template in firefox?

```
<polymer-element name="color-sample" attributes="color border">
    <template>
        <style>
            .swatch {
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                margin-right: 0.5em;
                background-color: {{ swatchColor }};
                border: 1px solid {{ borderColor }};
            }
        </style>
        <div id="sample" layout horizontal center>
            <div class="swatch"></div>
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            color: "white",
            border: "lightGrey",
            ready: function() {
                this.swatchColor = CoreStyle.g.theme[this.color];
                this.borderColor = CoreStyle.g.theme[this.border];
                console.log(this.swatchColor);
                console.log(this.borderColor);
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I should also point out that if I use inline styles directly on the `.swatch` div, then the binding seems to work fine, but I'm specifically looking for a solution to bind to the css directly to keep the html clean.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found the problem right after I posted.
Data binding isn't fully supported in `<style>` under the shadow dom.[1]

[1] https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/456